# Store time() as timestamp in mysql

Tags: php, time, unix-timestamp

How to store the current time (as in `time()`) into the mysql database as a timestamp?

I tried this query:

```
UPDATE users 
  SET last_login = '1360826987' 
  WHERE username = 'test' 
   AND password = 'test'
```

where 1360826987 is my current time via `time()`

Comment: shouldnt that be **last_login = 1360826987** ? without the single quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Use the NOW function of mysql instead.

```
UPDATE users SET last_login = NOW() ...
```

Comment: That will give you the server time!

Comment: You can set the timezone both in mysql and php so I don't get the point.

Comment: The application could be in a different timezone then the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. But make sure that the field accepts Integers.

```
 Type INT
```

Answer (score 0):

timestamp fields stores value in 2013-02-14 13:10:41 this format.  so use now() in your query